# C++ Reading in a string followed by two doubles

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, filestream, ifstream

I am getting the following error when trying to read in to a string then two doubles from a file:

> Error: no operator ">>" matches these operands
>              operand types are: std::ifstream >> std::string

**For the following code:**

```
std::string name;
double mass(0), radius(0), gravity(0);
std::ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("solSystem.txt", std::ios::app);
inCheck(inFile);
while (inFile >> name >> radius >> mass)
{
    someFunction(name, radius, mass);
}
inFile.close();
```

I have used the same code before `(std::ifstream >> std::string)` without problem however in that instance the input file had only characters.

**This is the input file:**

```
Sun       6.96e+08    1.989e+30
Mercury   2.44e+06    3.285e+23
Venus     6.052e+06   4.867e+24
Earth     6.371e+06   5.972e+24
Mars      3.39e+06    6.39e+23
Jupiter   6.9911e+07  1.898e+27
Saturn    5.8232e+07  5.683e+26
Uranus    2.5362e+07  8.681e+25
Neptune   2.4622e+07  1.024e+26
Pluto     1.186e+06   1.309e+22
```

Before you answer, I am looking for a solution to this yes, but I also want to know why I am getting this error that I might avoid it in the future.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted: it compiles for me after including `<fstream>` and `<string>`, commenting out the `inCheck` and `someFunction` lines, and wrapping it in `int main() { ... }`.  Did you forget the `#include`s?

Comment: `std::ifstream` is based on `std::basic_istream`, and `operator>>(std::basic_istream&, std::string&)` is implemented in the `<string>` header.  I agree with the other comments, there is likely something in your other headers that is interfering with this.

Comment: *"included all the appropriate header files "* - I suggest you get rid of everything *except* those two headers, and try commenting out the `inCheck` and `someFunction` lines.  If that then works, then something in the other headers is breaking things.  There might be a `namespace` that wasn't closed, a conflicting preprocessor macro etc....

Comment: Went back through and found the error. Thank you for bringing my attention to the headers. One of my custom headers was written for another program (before I learnt about them and why not to include other headers in them :O) and had other headers included in it causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So anyone who stumbles upon this issue as well can find a resolution.

1. Check to make sure all needed header files are included
2. Check any custom headers to see if you include other headers in them.... this can cause issues like it did for me